# Z3 print evaluation result

Tags: c++, c, z3

In Z3, how can we write a program to get the result from evaluation? By default `model.eval(expression)` will return another expression of the evaluation result. How can I assign the result to a type-specific data? Below is what I want to do in my program.

```
int a = model.eval(x + 1)  // compiler error
```

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes models are not complete. For instance, when nothing depends on the value of `x`, then Z3 may not assign any value at all to it, i.e., you're free to chose whatever value suits you. The `eval` function has a second argument, which, when set to `true`, will enable model completion, i.e., `eval` will substitute those don't-cares with some legal value (often 0).

Z3-ints are actual integers, not C/C++-ints smaller than 2^32-1, so the conversion is not performed automatically. If you know that in your application this will always be ok, and that `eval` will always return a numeral, then you can use [Z3_get_numeral_int](http://z3prover.github.io/api/html/group__capi.html#ga2d57bd6f0d1cb1f98835a5f38a9dc4bb%60) to perform that conversion.